# runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference with loop

Tags: loops, go, pointers

I am trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/description/?envType=study-plan&id=level-1

Input: head = [1,2,3,4,5]

This is my code:

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev *ListNode
    prev = nil
    for head.Next != nil {
        head, head.Next, prev = head.Next, prev, head
    }
    if head.Next == nil {
        head.Next = prev
    }
    return head
}
```

After running, the program gives an error: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference.
Please explain to me why this error occurs

With Input: head = [1,2,3,4,5]. I hope to do the loop 4 times until head.Next == nil. But something not as I expected happened.

Comment: When the panic occurs, the error readout should tell you what line the it occurs on. This information will help you or someone else debug the code, so please include it in your question.

Comment: if head is nil -> head.Next will be error liek you give

Comment: Include a check `if head != nil` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I found it. In leetcode, program give me out put of 3 examples. I asked a question about example 1 but didn't realize it was an error for example 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if head is nil -> head.Next will be error like you given

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev *ListNode
    prev = nil
    for head != nil && head.Next != nil {
        head, head.Next, prev = head.Next, prev, head
    }
    if  head != nil && head.Next == nil {
        head.Next = prev
    }
    return head
}
```

and more simple is :

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev *ListNode
    prev = nil
    for head != nil {
        head, head.Next, prev = head.Next, prev, head
    }
    if head == nil {
        head = prev
    }
    return head
}
```

Comment: I know I should not dereferencing a nil pointer. But I think head.Next == nill occur before head == nil. Why the loop not stop after 4 times when head.Next == nil.

Comment: head.Next  will never be nil, due to you set it to prev

Comment: The error I'm asking is for another input. I didn't realize leetcode gave the error on the same screen. However, your solution helped me when learning about pointers in Go. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `for head.Next != nil`, because if head is nil then you're dereferencing a nil pointer, which results in the panic.

To avoid this, you need to include a check that `head` is not nil.

Your code could look something like this:

```
func reverseList(head *ListNode) *ListNode {
    var prev *ListNode
    prev = nil
    if head != nil {
        for head.Next != nil {
            head, head.Next, prev = head.Next, prev, head
        }
        if head.Next == nil {
            head.Next = prev
        }
    }
    return head
}
```